# No first_name or user_firstname property in WP_User object

Tags: user-meta, mu-plugins

I'm writing a basic plugin. Here's my code:

```
$new_user = get_userdata($user_id);

$first_name1 = $new_user->user_firstname;
$last_name1 = $new_user->user_lastname;
    echo "<" . $first_name1 . $last_name1 . ">";
    //returns: <>

$first_name2 = $new_user-first_name;
$last_name2 = $new_user->last_name;
    echo "<" . $first_name2 . $last_name2 . ">";
    //returns: <>
```

According to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Notes), this should work, but when I echo `$first_name` or `$last_name` they're empty. Strangely, *THIS* does work:

```
    $id = $new_user->ID;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I `var_dump`ed  `$new_user` and those properties aren't in there! Is this because I'm calling it from inside a plugin in the /mu-plugins directory? Do those properties get added later?

```
object(WP_User)#334 (7) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#330 (10) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "758" ["user_login"]=> string(7) "emerson" ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$BB2PuvRbyGUSVZR1M8FLSujPvMO2MW0" ["user_nicename"]=> string(7) "emerson" ["user_email"]=> string(16) "123esl@gmail.com" ["user_url"]=> string(0) "" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2012-08-17 01:03:27" ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0) "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_name"]=> string(7) "emerson" } ["ID"]=> int(758) ["caps"]=> array(1) { ["subscriber"]=> string(1) "1" } ["cap_key"]=> string(15) "wp_capabilities" ["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "subscriber" } ["allcaps"]=> array(15) { ["read"]=> bool(true) ["level_0"]=> bool(true) ["read_questions"]=> bool(true) ["read_answers"]=> bool(true) ["publish_questions"]=> bool(true) ["immediately_publish_questions"]=> bool(true) ["publish_answers"]=> bool(true) ["read_private_forums"]=> bool(true) ["publish_topics"]=> bool(true) ["edit_topics"]=> bool(true) ["publish_replies"]=> bool(true) ["edit_replies"]=> bool(true) ["assign_topic_tags"]=> bool(true) ["access_s2member_level0"]=> bool(true) ["subscriber"]=> string(1) "1" } ["filter"]=> NULL }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the function [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

```
$new_user = get_userdata($user_id);

// get all the meta data of the user
$new_user_data = get_user_meta( $user_id );

// get the first name of the user as a string
$new_user_firstname = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the same page you referred, those two lines should be like:

```
$first_name = $new_user->first_name;
$last_name = $new_user->last_name;
```

Please check [this section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Accessing_Usermeta_Data).

Comment: I tried that as well and it also didn't work. When I print out the variables I get nothing.

Comment: I var_dumped the user object and for some reason none of those properties are in there.

Comment: First make sure the user has something in those fields that means user has firstname and lastname fields filled. I've also seen those two properties are not listed when you `var_dump` the user object but they are clearly shown when you use the property `var_dump($new_user->first_name);`

Comment: No. `var_dump($new_user->first_name)` is an empty string.

Comment: Also, I know those properties are filled in because I can see them in the user's profile in the admin screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've just stumbled across the same issue and your theory that mu-plugin may be factor is entirely correct.

Funnily enough it's not that the code itself is in a php file with mu-plugin, but rather that the call is initiated there. For example I had an "add_action" line in php file located in mu-plugins but did in fact call a function in my functions.php file. The result was I wasn't seeing the first name and last name. I moved that one "add_action" line in to my functions.php and then I got the metadata as expected!

So it's not so much an answer but I wanted to confirm that have to move this out of mu-plugins to get the desired result. I haven't delved further into the WP code yet to see if there are any clues as to why this would be the case. I do intend on raising a bug report though.

PS I've been testing this on WP 3.4 and 3.4.2